# Put, update, and get SSM Parameters with CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-ssm, aws-parameter-store

I am wondering if (and how) the following scenario's can be implemented using AWS CDK (Java):

**Scenario 1**: upload a `StringListParameter` object with two values to SSM. For example, I would do the following:

```
new StringListParameter(this, "some-id", StringListParameterProps.builder()
                .parameterName("/some/path/name")
                .stringListValue(List.of("value A", "value B"))
                .build());
```

Then, some other CDK stack fetches the StringListParameter and updates it like so:

```
IStringListParameter param = StringListParameter.fromStringListParameterName(this, "some-other-id", "/some/path/name");
        List<String> stringListValue = param.getStringListValue();
        stringListValue.add("value C");
```

And then puts this parameter in the AWS parameter store.

Scenario 2: put a number of SSM parameters in the parameter store that all share a common base path. Another CDK stack can then fetch all SSM parameters that have this common basepath. For example:

```
new StringParameter(this, "some-id-a", StringParameterProps.builder()
                .parameterName("/some/name/a")
                .stringValue("value A")
                .build());

new StringParameter(this, "some-id-b", StringParameterProps.builder()
                .parameterName("/some/name/b")
                .stringValue("value B")
                .build());
```

Another stack can then get every parameter with `some/name`.

Is this possible without use of a custom resource?

Looking for some ideas!

---

Edit 1

The consuming CDK stack would use the StringListParameter like this:

```
// import StringListParameter from SSM
List<String> lst = StringListParameter.valueForTypedListParameter(this, "/env/service/parameter-name");

// add a new value to the StringListParameter (so update)
lst.add("new value");

// put updated version of StringListParameter on SSM
new StringListParameter(this, "some id", StringListParameterProps.builder()
    .parameterName("/dev/ca2service/cluster-consumers")
    .stringListValue(lst)
    .build());
```

Apps basically should be able to update the StringListParameter...

I realize that it's not possible in the way I'm explaining it, but I'm looking for some solution / alternative to this.

Comment: Are the stacks in the same CDK app?

Comment: @fedonev No, the stacks would be in different CDK apps. There would be a central one for the database and about 5 other ones

Comment: Can you add an example of how the consuming stacks would use the parameters?

Comment: @fedonev I have provided an example

Comment: So: the "5 apps" should, when deployed, push an arbitrary value onto an existing list-like data structure. \*Getting\* the existing values isn't strictly a requirement.  \*Appending\* is the end goal, which may require a read op to work.